# Existing express email validation

Tags: node.js, express

I noticed that express has some sort of validation for email in forms. Can this be removed, or used for other input types as well? See picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgq2K.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is html, not specific to express. You may use `<input type="text">` instead of  `<input type="email">`.

Read also: http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/